# Force div to accomidate image (min-height not working)?

Tags: html, css

I've got a bunch of divs, one after the next, each with an image inside it. When I set `min-height` to a value higher than the height of the image, everything works fine:

[image]

But if I have it set to 50px while the image is 100+px, the images kind of "cascade"

[image]

What can I do to force the div to be at least as tall as the image inside it?

CSS

```
body {
    background: #cccccc;
    margin: 0px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333333;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.reply {
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.post {
    padding-top: 10px;
    /*background-color: #ff0000;*/
}
.postimage {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.postcomment {

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reply">
            One
            <div class="post">
                <img class="postimage" src="http://i1.minus.com/jfdkd7lABbSp8.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reply">
            Two
            <div class="post">
                <img class="postimage" src="http://i1.minus.com/jfdkd7lABbSp8.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reply">
            Three
            <div class="post">
                <img class="postimage" src="http://i1.minus.com/jfdkd7lABbSp8.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reply">
            Four
            <div class="post">
                <img class="postimage" src="http://i1.minus.com/jfdkd7lABbSp8.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `clear: left` to your div.

See this?

```
.postimage {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

When you float the contents of the div, the div does not stretch vertically to accommodate.

So, adding this:

```
.reply {
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px;
    clear: left;
}
```

Will resolve the issue.

**Alternate solution**
Another solution which I tend to prefer is to use the `overflow` hack, rather than clear:

```
.reply {
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You would expect that this would hide the part of the image below the div, but it has a different result: The `overflow: hidden` does not hide the contents, but rather causes the div to stretch down to contain the entire image.

Note: for this method to work on older browsers, you *must* specify a width (notice that I added that in the css above).

Comment: @See my "alternate solution", which solves your issue (my answer has been edited)

Comment: The `overflow` method does work. Any idea why the `clear` method doesn't?

Comment: Absolutely.  Clear is causing the div to clear any *previously floated elements*.  It does not cause the div to clear it's contents, but rather to clear any floats *before* it.  The overflow method causes the div to clear it's contents.