# How to get a div with extrinsic height and intrinsic width inside a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

#### Problem

Say we have a vertical (i.e. flex-direction: column) flexbox container with a given width and height. The flexbox contains divs and each div contains an image.

- All divs and images are supposed to shrink/grow by the same percentage to fill the height of the flexbox, which is achieved by using flex-shrink and/or flex-grow.
- All images are supposed to keep their aspect ratio (i.e. no stretching), which is achieved by leaving their css "width" attribute unset.
- Each div is supposed to have the same width as the image that's inside of it, which I expected to achieve with "width: min-content" or "width: max-content" or "width: fit-content", but this **does not work**.

How can the third point be achieved?

*Note: It seems to work outside of flexbox.*

#### Example

In the example below the div with id "imagecontainer" does not reduce its width when its height is shrunk below flex-basis, even though its content reduces in width.
However, having the same div outside of a flexbox makes it reduce its width correctly when it forces its child image to become smaller through height constraints.

How do I make the "imagecontainer" div in the flexbox scale its width with the image (so that the red div in the first example has the same size as the red div in the third example)?

```html
Image in flex container with limited height
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; border: 1px solid black; height: 110px; width: 200px; align-items: flex-start;">
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="position: relative; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 150px; min-height: 0; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="max-height: 150px; height: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>

Original image<br />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="border: 1px solid black;" />

<br />
Image in just a simple div with limited height
<div style="position: relative; height: 110px; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content;">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="max-height: 150px; height: 100%;" />
</div>
```

#### Edit:

Based on one of the answers below, this is a version that solves the problem on Chrome but doesn't work on Firefox. The only significant change from the example above to make it work was to add "height: 100%" on the "imagecontainer" div.

```html
Image in flex container with limited height
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; border: 1px solid black; height: 110px; width: 200px; align-items: flex-start;">
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="position: relative; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 120px; min-height: 0; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content; height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.png" style="max-height: 120px; height: 100%;" />
  </div>
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="position: relative; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 150px; min-height: 0; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: fit-content; height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="max-height: 150px; height: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>

Original image<br />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="border: 1px solid black;" />

<br />
Image in just a simple div with limited height
<div style="position: relative; height: 110px; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content;">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="max-height: 150px; height: 100%;" />
</div>
```

#### Edit Solution:

Based on the accepted answer the solution for the example above is this (calculating height percentages based on the values that would otherwise be the flex-basis):

```html
Image in flex container with limited height
<div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 110px; width: 200px;">
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red;height: calc(100% / (270 / 120)); width: max-content;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.png" style="height: 100%;" />
  </div>
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red;height: calc(100% / (270 / 150)); width: max-content;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="height: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note that this doesn't require flexbox anymore.*

Comment: you want that the size of `"imagecontainer"` to depend on its child size

Comment: Yes, but how? I already tried "width: min-content" but it still fills the width of the parent-flexbox instead. The image itself has the correct size though.

Comment: that can be good Imagine the width of image is `1800px` how will your `div` looks like I think what could be better is to set the size of  `"imagecontainer"` and make its child to fit in

Comment: Setting the size of the container would introduce a lot of redundant size specifications. The content is designed to scale properly so the container should just keep containing it properly from the instrintic width.

Comment: OK my be using `padding` instead of using `height` will help you but you have to set `width` and the container will expand according to the size of its children

Comment: If there is no other way I'll do that but it's gonna be really messy. Still hoping there's a way to avoid setting the width rather than the height.

Comment: no to set the `width` doesn't prevent `container` to expand in wide. it expands both in width and height

Comment: I know but I don't want the width to be the constraint because the space the flexbox is filling is vertically limited, not horizontally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217697/discussion-between-gad-and-marius).

Comment: you will accept an answer saying that this is not possible with CSS only and explaining why?

Comment: It seems like we're getting closer. There's already a solution with CSS only that works on chrome here. But if it really shouldn't be possible based on the current CSS specifications, then any possibly working answer would not be robust to future implementation changes anyway, so yes, the explanation should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `max-height: calc(100% / (total height / own height))` and `height: 100%` for `#imagecontainer` it will work on Firefox also. [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62920463/10698741)

```html
Image in flex container with limited height
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; border: 1px solid black; height: 110px; width: 200px; align-items: flex-start; ">
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="position: relative; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 120px; min-height: 0; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content; max-height: calc(100% / (270 / 120));height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.png" style=" height: 100%;" />
  </div>
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="position: relative; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 150px; min-height: 0; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: fit-content; max-height: calc(100% / (270 / 150));height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style=" height: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>

Original image<br />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="border: 1px solid black;" />

<br />
Image in just a simple div with limited height
<div style="position: relative; height: 110px; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content;">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="max-height: 150px; height: 100%;" />
</div>
```

If there are 3 elements in flex container:

```html
Image in flex container with limited height
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; border: 1px solid black; height: 110px; width: 200px; align-items: flex-start;">
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="position: relative; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 120px; min-height: 0; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content; max-height: calc(100% / (420 / 120)); height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.png" style=" height: 100%;" />
  </div>
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="position: relative; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 150px; min-height: 0; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content; max-height: calc(100% / (420 / 150));height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style=" height: 100%;" />
  </div>
   <div id="imagecontainer" style="position: relative; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 150px; min-height: 0; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content; max-height: calc(100% / (420 / 150));height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style=" height: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>

Original image<br />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="border: 1px solid black;" />

<br />
Image in just a simple div with limited height
<div style="position: relative; height: 110px; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content;">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="max-height: 150px; height: 100%;" />
</div>
```

Comment: the code can be simplified like this: https://jsfiddle.net/98a0exLd/3/  and it works because the sum of all heights is exactly equal to 100% which will avoid us dealing with shrinking or growing (or min-height issue). Any combination giving a sum equal to 100% will do the job

Comment: Thank you, this solves it. There is no need to make it a flex box in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

Given the example snippet, I assume you want the red bordered container to be just as big as the inner image. The black bordered container should not change in size.

To accomplish this, it is enough to add `display: flex;` to `#imagecontainer`.

You have set some flex properties on it (`flex-basis` and `flex-shrink`) that do nothing without a flex element.

By default, the display value of a div is `block`.

Snippet:

```html
Image in flex container with limited height
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; border: 1px solid black; height: 110px; width: 200px; align-items: flex-start;">
  <div id="imagecontainer" style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 150px; min-height: 0; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="max-height: 150px; height: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>

Original image<br />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="border: 1px solid black;" />

<br />
Image in just a simple div with limited height
<div style="position: relative; height: 110px; border: 1px solid red; width: min-content;">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="max-height: 150px; height: 100%;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks if the height of the flexbox changes (e.g. height: 100% of parent element and window resizing can break it). This can be tested by changing the height of the flexbox in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for extra space at right**

Actually, according to me, first the `img` overflows out of `flex` container (since `img` loading takes time i.e. out of flow) and then `height` is shrunk due to covering `div`. The `width` of `img` adjusts as it should be but the `width` of covering `div` doesn't changes. There is no property here to do that.

You could simply do something like this...

```css
.a {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.a>div {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  min-height: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.a>div>img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't requires extra dimension specifications and adjusts well.

I looked at your css properties, their seemed issue with `min-height` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482166/force-div-to-accomidate-image-min-height-not-working).

Edit: I have added `min-height: 0;` to `.a>div` just before `height` property. I tried a lot of solutions but maybe this order was important. I spotted the order from the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62920463/13192834). Thanks to him.

Comment: Unfortunately this only seems to work for a single div inside the flexbox. Once there's a second div it starts overflowing the flexbox.

Comment: Yeah that's true. If you have fixed number of images, then you can set `height` as `100%/n` (n = no. of images) or you can pass the `n` through js on `.a>div` element. Putting relative `height` to `<img>` without any `height` property on its container element will only mess things up. Your overall objective could have been much easy for `flex-direction: row` check [this](https://codepen.io/romanp/pen/ZoZZQP). But this logic isn't working for `flex-direction: column` maybe that's because how relative `height` is calculated.

Comment: The number of images is fixed but they are different size so it's not just 100%/n. Manually calculating the percentages in advance is the next best workaround I guess, but it's not very nice/clean since it makes tweaking the design so much more complicated.

Comment: I tried a lot of stuff, but can't find an elegant solution and I guess its just `(100/n)%` because vertically all the images will have same size. i.e. same `height`. Just the width will vary.

Comment: Yea but that would correspond to flexbox having the same flex-basis for all elements. To get results similar to having different flex-basis values for each child means the height percentage depends on the hypothetical flex-basis value. 

Now that I think about it, the most elegant solution might be to use flexbox for the initial dimensions and have javascript code to convert it to your solution after the initial page render (calculating the percentages in the process). That would give us the best of both worlds: easy design and robust behavior.

Comment: Yeah that could be the best! Maybe you can put some js on `<img>` with `onload` attribute. Good luck! If you don't mind I have raised another question regarding this focusing more specifically. I really wanna now a better question.

Comment: The edited version works perfectly in Chrome but doesn't work properly in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for your problem.

```html
    <div
      style="display: flex; border: 1px solid black; width: 200px;"
    >
      <div
        id="imagecontainer"
        style="
          display: flex;
          height: auto;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border: 1px solid red;
        "
      >
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" style="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    
    Original image<br />
    <img
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png"
      style="border: 1px solid black;"
    />
    
    <br />
    Image in just a simple div with limited height
    <div
      style="
        position: relative;
        height: 110px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: min-content;
      "
    >
      <img
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png"
        style="max-height: 150px; height: 100%;"
      />
    </div>
```

You simply didn't need most of the flex properties on the img container and it's parent divs. I have used all the unused code from your HTML.

Crucial advice: You should never use inline styling like you did here. I repeat never.

Comment: This is not a vertical flexbox and making it vertical (adding flex-direction: column) breaks this. The flexbox will have multiple divs which are supposed to be arranged vertically, not horizontally (as per the problem statement).