# How to fit flex item's width to content image in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a `<div>` with `display: flex;`, `flex-direction: column` and fixed `height` and `width`. There are flex items containing images. After applying `min-height: 0`, as required, the images distributed vertically equal. But the flex items have some extra space left out. I can't remove this.

I tried all kind of stuff but no luck. please help.

```css
.a {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.a>div {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  min-height: 0;
}

.a>div>img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the solutions below doesn't work on Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `height: calc(100% / 3)` to `.a > div`.

Edit: Works on Firefox also.

```css
.a {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.a > div {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  min-height: 0;
  height: calc(100% / 3); /* 3 is flex items in flex container */
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.a > div > img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddling with your post, And I don't know why but adding `height:100%` to your flex items worked.

So yeah solution is to add `height:100%` in the flex items.

```css
.a {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex-grow:0;
}

.a>div {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  min-height: 0;
  height:100%;
}

.a>div>img {
height:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work on Firefox